# Calculate the number of identical routes and apply in another function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am doing a lab and faced with such a task:

> Identify stages of the routes with the maximum length, the route with
>   the largest number of tourists that went through it

I wrote this code, but somehow it does not work correctly.

```
SELECT Max(Stage.Length) 
FROM (           Route 
      INNER JOIN Stage ON Route.id = Stage.route 
    ) INNER JOIN Travel ON Route.id = Travel.Route
WHERE Stage.route = (SELECT `Travel.route` 
                      FROM `Travel` 
                      GROUP BY `Travel.Route` 
                      HAVING count(*)>1);
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Max(Етап.Довжина) AS Выражение1
FROM (Маршрут INNER JOIN Етап ON Маршрут.id = Етап.Маршрут) INNER JOIN Подоріж ON Маршрут.id = Подоріж.Маршрут
WHERE (((Етап.Маршрут) In (SELECT t.Маршрут 
                      FROM Подоріж t
                      GROUP BY t.Маршрут
                      HAVING count(*)>1)));
```